# Why a big size of array cannot be generated while a vector can?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, containers, limit

I have the following code :

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int N=100000;
int main() {

    default_random_engine Generator(time(0));
    uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(0.0f,nextafter(1.0f, DBL_MAX));

    array<float,N> a{0};
    //vector<float> a(N,0);



    for ( auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it ){
        *it=dist(Generator);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The ambiguity I have is that array a can be generated when N is 100000 but when N becomes 1 million, it immediately exits the program with exit value of not zero! in another word, it crashes. But, when I use vector instead of an array, even millions of elements can be generated exactly by this way. Can anyone explain this? Does the array have some kind of limitation to produce a large size of numbers?

Comment: Use std::vector to put the storage on the heap. The stack is a limited resource usually between 1 and 10 MB depending on the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [`array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) allocates it's memory on the stack, while the [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) allocates memory on the heap. You can allocate the `array` on the heap as well, with `new` or by using a [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [`unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) like so:

```cpp
shared_ptr<array<float,N>> a(new array<float,N>{0});
float v = (*a)[10]; // dereference for operator access
```

Comment: Actually, both the `std::array` and the `std::vector` objects are allocated on the stack. However, the `std::array` object contains all the array data, whereas the `std::vector` object just contains some metadata and a pointer to the actual data, which is stored on the heap. See the comments section of the other answer for further information.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the memory you allocate with array is on the stack and your program stack is not large enough so you get a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) when using an array. However, when you use a vector, you allocate the memory on the heap.

If you still prefer to use `std::array`, you can put the array on the heap: `new std::array<float, N>(0)`.

Comment: so, even if I am not using any "new" or "make_unique", the vector generated by the above code will be on the heap?

Comment: Yes, `std::vector` uses the heap. It has to, because vectors are dynamically resizable. `std:array` can go on the stack because it is fixed-size.

Comment: @MAero2020 The **vector** object will not be on the heap. But the vector object is very small, and instead of containing the array of elements within itself, it indirectly points to an array which was allocated dynamically.

Comment: @eerorika thanks for the explanation! I got confused a bit whether finally, vector elements will be on the heap or not

Comment: your link to SO is aimed at wikipedia.  One sec will fix...

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont :D